# Webbrowser control inject JS and CSS

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have `Webrowser` control in my application and I want to inject `css` and `javascript` into it.
In my  `winform` app I have done it with :

```
string jqueryCode = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"JQuery.js");

HtmlElement head2 = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl2 = browser.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element2 = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl2.DomElement; 
element2.text = jqueryCode;
head2.AppendChild(scriptEl2);


string css = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"local_page.css");

HTMLDocument CurrentDocument = (HTMLDocument)browser.Document.DomDocument;
IHTMLStyleSheet styleSheet = CurrentDocument.createStyleSheet("", 0);
styleSheet.cssText = css;

string javaScriptCode = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Script.js");

HtmlElement head = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = browser.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
element.text = javaScriptCode;
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);

browser.InvokeScript("myfunction");
```

And it works perfectly. And now in the `WPF` application I do it with :

```
string jqueryCode = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"JQuery.js");

var doc = (HTMLDocument)browser.Document;
var head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head").Cast<HTMLHeadElement>().First();
var script = (IHTMLScriptElement)doc.createElement("script");
script.text = jqueryCode;
head.appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)script);


string css = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"local_page.css");

var doc2 = (HTMLDocument)browser.Document;
var head2 = doc2.getElementsByTagName("head").Cast<HTMLHeadElement>().First();
var script2 = (IHTMLStyleSheet)doc2.createStyleSheet("");
script2.cssText = css;

string javaScriptCode = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Script.js");

var doc3 = (HTMLDocument)browser.Document;
var head3 = doc3.getElementsByTagName("head").Cast<HTMLHeadElement>().First();
var script3 = (IHTMLScriptElement)doc3.createElement("script");
script3.text = javaScriptCode;
head3.appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)script3);

browser.InvokeScript("myfunction");
```

And it makes problems. Any idea what the problems can be?

Comment: "And it make problems" - WTF?

Comment: @Uwe Keim It's a long script that won't work in WPF browser and work in winform browser. and i want to know if i did something wrong in the inject.